# How change the default font for comments in Windows 7 + Excel 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

In Windows XP + Excel 2007 one could change the default font for comments in Excel with: right-click on desktop, properties, appearance, advanced, tooltip, enter size.

But I could not find this options sequence in Windows 7 + Excel 2010.

A similar looking dialog appears in Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization: window color. But it has no 'advanced' button.

I already have a macro that works to change the font of all the existing comments in a worksheet.

But how does one change the default for all new comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ToolTip trick still works in Windows 7 for Excel 2010, you can change the ToolTip font in Windows 7 by using the following method(s):

**For Windows 7 Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate, or Enterprise:**

1. Right click on a empty space on the desktop and click on `Personalize`.
2. Click on the `Window Color` link at the bottom of the window.
3. Click on the `Advanced appearance settings...` link.
4. Select an Item that you want to change the font for.

**For Windows 7 Starter or Home Basic:**

1. Open the Control Panel (icons view), and click on the `Display` icon.
2. In the left blue pane, click on the `Change color scheme` link.
3. Click on the `Advanced` button.
4. From the drop down menu select TipTool and
5. Select an Item that you want to change the font for.

Comment: Hi thanks. I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise. I get to point 2 but there is no "advanced settings" link. That's where I get stuck...

Comment: Oops, feeling really stupid now. It works: step 3 is just absent now. From 'window color' you directly choose 'item' = tooltip. Thanks so much!